# Extract macro parameters from target name in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a bunch of lines like this in my makefile, in different permutations. I want to automate them with a general rule, so if I type `$ make foo-WHATEVER`, make knows how to build it from `foo.c` and relevant -D flags.

```
foo-PARAMA.o: foo.c
foo-PARAMA.o: CPPFLAGS += -DPARAMA

foo-PARAMA-PARAMB.o: foo.c
foo-PARAMA-PARAMB.o: CPPFLAGS += -DPARAMA -DPARAMB

foo-PARAMA-PARAMB-PARAMC.o: foo.c
foo-PARAMA-PARAMB-PARAMC.o: CPPFLAGS += -DPARAMA -DPARAMB -DPARAMC
```

Comment: This can be done, but it's a very un-Make-like way to pass parameters.

Comment: What is a more Make-like way?

Comment: `make foo EXTRAPARAMS="PARAMA PARAMB PARAMC"` and in the makefile `CPPFLAGS += $(addprefix -D, $(EXTRAPARAMS))`

Comment: That's neat. How would I get this into a the file `foo-PARAMA-PARAMB-PARAMC.o` and eventually `foo-PARAMA-PARAMB-PARAMC.elf`? I need separate executables for each combination.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try something like this:

```
foo-%.o : foo.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(addprefix -D,$(subst -, ,$*)) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

but my suspicion is that you're really going to want to do this for "any source file" not just `foo.c`.  That's much harder because you can't have multiple patterns in a single target or prerequisite.

For that you'll have to know the list of source files up-front and use `eval`:

```
SRCS = foo.c bar.c baz.c biz.c

define make-pattern
$1-%.o : $1.c
        $$(CC) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(addprefix -D,$$(subst -, ,$$*)) $$(CFLAGS) -o $$@ -c $$<
endif

$(foreach S,$(SRCS),$(eval $(call make-pattern,$S)))
```

Comment: Depending on the combinations of files and flags, it may make more sense to structure `make-pattern` as `%-$1.o: %.c; $$(CC) $$(CPPFLAGS) -D$1`... and the do `foreach` over all the flag combos wanted instead of all the files.

Comment: MadScientist: you are correct, in the limit case I'd like to do this to any file. In my actual use right now though, only the main .c file that does anything meaningful with these parameters. it then passes them to functions from other files as runtime arguments.

@Chris Dodd: I like that it forces me to enumerate the possible flags. Trying to compile a non-existent source fails noisily, but passing a flag that the .c doesn't look at "succeeds" silently. I'm going to try this and report here what comes out.

Comment: The question was _so if I type `$ make foo-WHATEVER`, make knows how to build it_  The use of _WHATEVER_ implies a free-form set of flags.  Chris's solution works if (a) all the flags are  known, (b) the combinations of flags that might be wanted are known, and (c) the order in which flags are provided is always the same.  Otherwise you'll be creating an explosion of different pattern rules to cover all the permutations.  If there are relatively few permutations it would make sense to do it that way, but there is no way to tell from the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, @MadScientist. The tags are known, but the permutations can quickly become a problem like you're saying. Part of the value of dialogue with you is getting clearer on my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do configuration management inside `make`. The problem is that `make` itself is not really equipped with such functionality. My guess is that at the time of its invention the extreme diversity of platforms which one day will run some unixoid build system simply wasn't foreseeable - so the main use case was to easily define a rather homogenous build with some small deviations.
Now, its 2019 and `make` is still around and supposedly with a larger user base than ever before. One possible remedy which has the advantage that it doesn't require any other tool is to use [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which is a GNUmake library for exactly this configuration purpose. Below I sketch a hypothetical config scenario:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

PLATFORM := $(shell uname)

# table of platforms with 2 columns. Don't forget that the leading element of every table must be an integer denoting the number of columns!
define AVAILABLE-PLATFORMS :=
2
CYGWIN?NT-4.?     toolX
CYGWIN?NT-10.?    toolY
Linux*            toolZ
FreeBSD           toolXYZ
endef

define ADDITIONAL-FLAGS :=
2
toolX   -Dfoo
toolY   -Dbar
toolZ   -Dbaz
toolXYZ  -Dfoo
toolXYZ  -Dbar
toolXYZ  -Dbaz
endef

# select column 2 from the table line(s) which glob-match the current platform:
USED-TOOL := $(call select,2,$(AVAILABLE-PLATFORMS),$$(call glob-match,$(PLATFORM),$$1))

# now select the right flags for the tool
CFLAGS_OPT := $(call select,2,$(ADDITIONAL-FLAGS),$$(call str-eq,$(USED-TOOL),$$1))

$(info $(USED-TOOL)  Options: $(CFLAGS_OPT))
```

Admittedly, this is a lemma on [Greenspun's tenth rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) but the other options (composing configuration information with a handful of external tools) aren't so attractive either.

Comment: Thank you, @Vroomfoundel. I am indeed trying to do configuration management, but a little different from what you describe. I'm using make to build an embedded system. The flags I'm passing in at compile time would be command-line switches in a normal environment. Since there is no way to pass arguments to a system without a UI, I'm building a version of the binary for each valid combination of flags. I'm with you on the the tenth rule.

Comment: Well, gmtt was written exactly with embedded systems in mind. The key idea is that selecting from tables is the most controlled way to configure such systems. What does not work with gmtt in your opinion?